# Android: How to determine if a view is pressed or released?

Tags: android, android-view

I know there is a `MotionEvent`, but this is a different case: I want a `View` to become larger and larger while I am touching on it, and shrinks down gradually to its original size if I am no longer pressing that `View`.

`onTouchEvent` is only called when I press the `View` for the first time (`ACTION_DOWN`); release the `View`(`ACTION_UP`); or scrub my finger around(`ACTION_MOVE`). They don't help my case. So I am wondering, are there any elegant solutions out there instead of using like a timer to solve the problem in low-level?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there's no really an elegant method to do that (if you consider using timers as inelegant). But I wouldn't really worry about using those sort of solutions. You can do it this way (assuming `view` is the `View` you're animating):

1. Add fields (to something that manages your `View` - an `Activity` or a `Fragment`):

```
private static final float SCALE_FACTOR = 0.2f;
private static final long STEP_DELAY = 300;
private Handler handler = new Handler();
private Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        view.animate().scaleXBy(SCALE_FACTOR).scaleYBy(SCALE_FACTOR);
        handler.postDelayed(runnable, STEP_DELAY);
    }
};
```

2. Setup an `OnTouchListener` for you `View`:

```
view.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        switch (event.getAction()) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                handler.postDelayed(runnable, STEP_DELAY);
                return true;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL:
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                userImage.animate().cancel();
                handler.removeCallbacks(mRunnable);
                return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
});
```

*Adjust `SCALE_FACTOR` and `STEP_DELAY` to exactly fit your needs.*